# <string> header works but not <cstring>

Tags: c++, string, cstring

I have three short files which I adapted from my project because they reproduce the errors I am having:

exp.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
}
```

parser.cpp

```
#include <cstring>
#include "parser.h"
```

parser.h

```
#ifndef PARSER_H_
#define PARSER_H_

#include <cstring>

class Parser{
public:
    Parser(std::string*);
    std::string* unprocessedInput;
};

#endif /* PARSER_H_ */
```

When I build the project, at the line,

```
Parser(std::string*)
```

I get the error message "expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token" and at the line,

```
std::string* unprocessedInput;,
```

I get the error "‘string’ in namespace ‘std’ does not name a type".

When I use <string> instead of <cstring> in either parser.cpp or parser.h, the project builds. I want to understand why <cstring> is not working. I need to work with null-terminated strings in my project.

Note that I have searched extensively for this. In my research I got the idea of using std::string instead of a string in a header file.

Comment: You are aware of the problem, so what is the point of your question? Just include the correct headers for what you are doing.

Comment: I want to work with null-terminated strings that's why I want to use <cstring>. If I work with <string> won't that mean I need to convert every string to cstring?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Header `<cstring>` contains standard C declarations of C header `<string.h>`
C++ header `<string>` contains the declaration of C++ standard class `std::string` (std::basic_string)

So `<cstring>` and `<string>` are different headers and contain different declarations.

According to the C++ Standard (relative to header `<cstring>`)

> 7 The contents are the same as the Standard C library header
>   `<string.h>`, with the change to memchr() specified in 21.8.